# Bootable NixOS ISOs not working (18.03.132847)

Tags: linux, boot, uefi, nixos

After following the [NixOS' Installation Guide](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/NixOS_Installation_Guide), I'm failing to create a bootable Installation ISO. I created [an issue](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/44888) for this on `NixOS/nixpkgs`. But I wanted to see if there was any knowledge here. Took a look around including [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764464/make-bootable-uefi-iso), and don't see a clear answer beyond what's already in the documentation.

**i)** Basically, when I try to write a bootable ISO to my USB stick, I can't make it boot. From the boot menu, I run the USB stick, and am immediately exited out of the boot process without any error message. I'm simply immediately placed back in the boot loader.

```
sudo dd if=~/Downloads/nixos-graphical-18.03.132847.aec217852f2-x86_64-linux.iso of=/dev/sda

sudo dd bs=1024 status=progress if=~/Downloads/nixos-graphical-18.03.132847.aec217852f2-x86_64-linux.iso of=/dev/sda
```

I also tried **ii)** reformatting the USB stick with `fdisk` (bootable, 1 partition, VFAT). And **iii)** calling `sync` after the dd write. No dice.

The simple `dd` copy command works on Ubuntu ISOs. Is there anything else I have to do for NixOS' ISO?

Comment: Are you sure `/dev/sda` is your USB stick? That's usually the first block device in the system, which tends to be the installed SSD/HDD.

Comment: Aside from that, they might just not provide bootable hybrid ISOs supporting UEFI.  If you're trying to install Nix anyways, maybe trying with a BIOS-based virtual machine would be better; if that works (and you need to run it on a UEFI-based host), try UEFI-based vm; if that works, try disabling SecureBoot on your host *and* boot off (external USB) DVD; if that works, you basically got only two choke points to explore.  You might also want to read this: http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html

Comment: @MichaelShigorin Bingo! I had to turn off "Secure Boot", as the NixOS installer doesn't sign it's ISOs. There's a brief blurb about it in its [UEFI_boot](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/NixOS_Installation_Guide#UEFI_boot) section. So I missed that. Much obliged!

Comment: @Mioriin Good point. Yeah I checked that, and the device was right. I ultimately got it working, as I had to turn off my BIOS' "Secure Boot" switch. Cheers.

Comment: @Nutritioustim Might be a good idea if you put that as an answer and marked it as accepted, so that others in the same situation can benefit from it. :)

Comment: Glad this helped; I've reposted as an answer for future reference, agreed.

Comment: By the way, I think you do not need to use `dd`: I make my installation USB drives for NixOS by simply copying (drag and drop) onto the USB drive. See my experience [here](https://superuser.com/a/796642).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They might just not provide bootable hybrid ISOs supporting UEFI.  If you're trying to install Nix anyways, maybe trying with a BIOS-based virtual machine would be better; if that works (and you need to run it on a UEFI-based host), try UEFI-based vm; if that works, **try disabling SecureBoot** on your host *and* boot off (external USB) DVD; if that works, you basically got only two choke points to explore.

You might also want to read [this excellent UEFI introduction](http://rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html) by Rod Smith (helped me a lot to implement UEFI support in ALT Linux).

Comment: This used to work at some point - I don't expect anyone would remove the hybrid ISO property since, but there may be some bugs...